# c++: pragma -std=c++11

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++

Здравствуйте! Как сказать компилятору (gcc и g++), чтоб он добавил строку `-std=c++11` при компиляции? Через pragma?

Comment: использовать gcc 6.4 и выше. Там 14 стандарт по  дефолту.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Никак. В G++ такой прагмы нет.

Такими вещами должна заниматься система сборки - cmake, make, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Обычно чтобы проверить код на наличие ошибок систему сборки проекта не используют, поскольку проще и быстрее натравить на выбранный файл компилятор, указав ему в качестве цели объектный модуль (-с). 
Вашу проблему можно решить разными способами в зависимостьи от того, как Вы запускаете компилятор и в какой операционной среде работаете. Тем не менее есть универсальный:
Нужно обернуть компилятор скриптом с таким же именем, который распарсит Ваш файл, найдет в нем, например, комментарий "// mode: -std=c++11" и добавит в аргументы командной строки компилятора нужный вам текст, после чего запустит, указав полный путь к компилятору.
Как под никсами, так и под виндовсами программы запускаются либо указанием полного пути к исполняемому файлу, либо путь ищется из переменной среды PATH. Порядок поиска нужно установить таким, чтобы ваш скрипт-обертка с именем компилятора находился раньше, чем сам компилятор. В никсах из коробки путь $HOME/bin всегда проверяется раньше, чем /usr/bin, где обычно лежат программы, поэтому обертку достаточно разместить в домашнем ~/bin. В виндовсах, скорее всего, придется подправить переменную PATH, указав в начале каталог с оберткой.
Если компилятор запускается из IDE или редактора, в котором можно в любое место строки вызова передать имя файла, то в unix-подобной среде можно обойтись без оборачивания компилятора, используя результат выполнения специального скрипта как часть строки вызова, аналогично тому, как это работает в pkgconfig. В slickedit'е, например, такая строка в параметрах настройки отдельного вызова компилятора у меня выглядит следующим образом

```
gcc -c -std=`~/bin/std-variant %f` ....
```

где ~/bin/std-variant -- скрипт, котороый принимает имя исходного файла (%f), парсит его и выводит ту строку стандарта, которую я задаю в нем в соответсвующем комментарии.